# Sign extension with unsigned long long

Tags: c

We found some strange values being produced, a small test case is below.
This prints "FFFFFFFFF9A64C2A" . Meaning the unsigned long long seems to have been sign extended.
But why ? 
All the types below are unsigned, so what's doing the sign extension ? The expected output
would be "F9A64C2A".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char a[] = {42,76,166,249};

    unsigned long long ts;
    ts = a[0] | a[1] << 8U | a[2] << 16U | a[3] << 24U;

    printf("%llX\n",ts);


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the expression `a[3] << 24U`, the `a[1]`  has type `unsigned char`. Now, the "integer promotion" converts it to `int` because:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may
>   be used:
>
> [...]
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to 
>   an `int`;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`.

([(draft) ISO/IEC 9899:1999](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), 6.3.1.1 2)

Please note also that the shift operators (other than most other operators) do *not* do the "usual arithmetic conversions" converting both operands to a common type. But

> The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

(6.5.7 3)

On a 32 bit platform, `249 << 24 = 4177526784` interpreted as an `int` has its sign bit set.

Just changing to

```
ts = a[0] | a[1] << 8 | a[2] << 16 | (unsigned)a[3] << 24;
```

fixes the issue (The suffix `U`for the constants has no impact).

Comment: @user964970: Read again.  The type of `x << y` has nothing to do with the type of `y`.

Comment: @user964970 didn't you read it? `The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.`

Answer (score 1):

```
 ts = ((unsigned long long)a[0]) | 
    ((unsigned long long)a[1] << 8U) | 
    ((unsigned long long)a[2] << 16U) | 
    ((unsigned long long)a[3] << 24U);
```

Casting prevents converting intermediate results to default int type.

Comment: But *why* is there an intermediate int result, when all types involved are unsigned types ? The culprit seems to only be the first `a[0] ` , replacing that with `(unsigned)a[0]` an all is well. But why.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the shifted a[i], when automatically converted from `unsigned char` to `int`, produce sign-extended values.

This is in accord with section 6.3.1 Arithmetic operands, subsection 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers, of C draft standard N1570, which reads, in part, "2. The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used: ... — An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int)
whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int. ... If an int can represent all values of the original type ..., the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions. ... 3. The integer promotions preserve value including sign."

See eg [www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

You could use code like the following, which works ok:

```
      int i;
      for (i=3, ts=0; i>=0; --i) ts = (ts<<8) | a[i];
```

Comment: All a[i]'s that are shifted, in the example code, have the right hand side as unsigned due to the U prefix on the constant. (e.g. << 8U) , meaning e.g. the expression  a[1] << 8U should have unsigned type already, according those rules.

Comment: @user964970: The culprit is not `a[0]`.  However, casting `a[0]` to `unsigned` forces the result of the bitwise or to be `unsigned`, which truncates the sign extension that appears in `a[3] << 24`, which is the real culprit.